# Similarity between variables when using calibration curves

Tags: classification, calibration

I'm reading through a text that is explaining calibration curves, and the following description is provided:

> To be well-calibrated, the probabilities must effectively reflect the true likelihood of the event of interest. Returning to the spam filter illustration, if a model produces a probability or probability-like value of 20 % for the likelihood of a particular e-mail to be spam, then this value would be well-calibrated if similar types of messages would truly be from that class on average in 1 of 5 samples.

What I don't understand is the *"similar types of messages"* part. How do calibration curves determine similarity between observations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarity is determined by the classifier that is being calibrated. This paragraph is saying that if we run our classifier on a pile of emails, then for all of the emails $x$ that we predict $p(y=\text{SPAM}\mid x)=0.2$ (i.e., emails that our classifier scores similarly), roughly 20% of them should actually be $\text{SPAM}$.

It may be helpful to think about calibrated outputs as an *interpretation* of a classification decision. It doesn't really add information to the decision function, it simply maps it to the interval $[0,1]$ so it can be *interpreted* as a probability.